# css menu 3 or 4 layers - confusing code

Tags: css

i'm new with css and got an code for a 2 layer css menu but i want 3 layers or 4 but its a bit confusing with ul ul li ul li hover a and so on. please can you help me? I`m trying it for 3 days but i only get the main menu and the second layer correctly styled...

```
/* Hauptmenü */

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration:none;
z-index:1;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
z-index:1;
}
ul li {
  font: bold 13px/18px sans-serif;

  display: inline-block;
  height:23px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px 8px 0px -4px;
  padding: 1px 5px 0px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index:1;
}

ul li:hover {
background: #db0133;
z-index:2;
}

/* Hauptmenü Ende*/







/* Untermenü 1*/
ul li ul li { 
font: normal 13px/18px sans-serif;
  background: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: block; 
  color: #000;
z-index:1;

}
ul li ul li:hover { 
font: normal 13px/18px sans-serif;
  background: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #db0133;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;

z-index:1;

}

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  z-index:2;
  width: 180px;
  margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;

}



ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 z-index:2;

}
/* Untermenü 1 Ende*/






/* Untermenü 2 */


ul li ul li ul li{
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  z-index:2;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 175px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;

}
ul li ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 z-index:2;

}

  /*Untermenü 2 Ende */

<!-- NAVIGATION ENDE -->
```

Comment: Post HTML? Preferably link to a JSFiddle that you have everything ready for us to fiddle with?

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the full code I am pretty sure that I know what you mean with "confusing".
when you style a ul-element, it will also affect the inner ul-elements, right?
(Same for the li-elements)

I recommend you this solution:

Classify your ul - hierarchy like this in your HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation-layer-0">
  <li>
      First layer
      <ul class="navigation-layer-1">
          <li>
              Second layer
              <ul class="navigation-layer-2">
                   <li>Third layer</li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Now in your CSS you can do the following to always style just one layer:

```
.navigation-layer-0 {
    /* properties for your first layer go here */
}

.navigation-layer-0 > li {
    /* properties for your first layer list-elements go here */
}

.navigation-layer-1 {
    /* properties for your second layer go here */
}

.navigation-layer-1 > li {
    /* properties for your second layer list-elements go here */
} 
/* same for third layer */
```

".navigation-layer-x > li" means, 
Matches any li element that is a direct child of an element .navigation-layer-x.

By this you only style the list-elements of one specific list-layer.

Hope this helps!